# Android service discovery failed exception

Tags: android, exception, bluetooth

In my android application I am using bluetooth. Everything works fine on the first connection attempt and there is no problem. However, after disconnecting and trying to connect for the second time I'm getting "service discovery failed exception" on:

```
socket.connect();
```

At first I thought that there is a problem in my disconnection but it seems to be fine on both
the client application and the server application (Both are android devices Galaxy sII)

In order to be able to connect again I restart the client device.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more of your code, so we can see exactly how connections and disconnections are being made.  You say that the disconnection seems fine on both sides--how are you confirming that?

You may want to look at the Bluetooth Chat example that comes with the Android SDK, if you haven't already, and install it on both devices and check that it works properly (and why).